# PySpark : how to write computation logic in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames with the following schema

df1 :

```
root
 |-- story_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

df2 :

```
root
 |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is sample data from both

df1 :

```
|story_id                          |uri                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0x5883d731edac1ca0d115c1ef05fb45e3|https://ilovupdates.com/i-know-what-you-did-last-summer-amazon-originals/|
|0x5883d731edac1ca0d115c1ef05fb45e3|https://ilovupdates.com/annabelle-sethupathi-2021-full-movie-download/|
|0x5883d731edac1ca0d115c1ef05fb45e3|https://ilovupdates.com/vicky-kaushal-biography/|
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

df2

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uri                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|https://tvnewsalert.com/topics/entertainment/                                  |
|https://tvnewsalert.com/private-vaccine-verification-app-portpass-sparks-privacy-security-concerns/|
|https://tvnewsalert.com/kota-factory-season-2-web-series-download-leaked-on-moviesflix-480p/        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Essentially df1 contains several urls for a given story id, and there are multiple story ids in df1.

df2 contains a set of master urls.

The task is to find out how many urls from each story id in df1 are present in the the master url set of df2

So for an input like :

df1

```
s1, url1
s1, url2
s1, url3
s2, url2
s2, url4
```

df2

```
url1
url3
url4
```

The output should be

```
s1, 2
s2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> The task is to find out how many urls from each story id in df1 are
> present in the the master url set of df2

You may join on `uri` to determine which `uri` is present in both before grouping and counting the number of `story_id`

```py
output_df = df1.join(df2,['uri'],"inner").groupBy("story_id").count()
output_df.show()
```

Let me know if this works for you.